# WKWebview getAllCookies crash in iOS 11.3

Tags: ios, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration, wkhttpcookiestore, ios11.3

We have recently migrated to WKWebview. We have added a listener for cookie change, to get the updated cookies and update our own store.

```
- (void)cookiesDidChangeInCookieStore:(WKHTTPCookieStore *)cookieStore {
    [cookieStore getAllCookies:^(NSArray* cookies) {
    }];
}
```

Once the controller is loaded, it calls cookiesDidChangeInCookieStore and crashes at "getAllCookies".But this crash happens only in TestFlight/Fabric build. Doesn't happen when i run the app directly on device from xcode (both in debug and release mode). Below is the crash report,

```
Thread 9 name:  WebThread
Thread 9 Crashed:
0   WebKit                          0x0000000192fbfc10 WebKit::CallbackMap::put+ 1186832 (WTF::Ref<WebKit::CallbackBase, WTF::DumbPtrTraits<WebKit::CallbackBase> >&&) + 128
1   WebKit                          0x0000000192fbfbb4 WebKit::CallbackMap::put+ 1186740 (WTF::Ref<WebKit::CallbackBase, WTF::DumbPtrTraits<WebKit::CallbackBase> >&&) + 36
2   WebKit                          0x00000001930490cc WebKit::CallbackID WebKit::CallbackMap::put<WTF::Vector<WebCore::Cookie, 0ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow, 16ul, WTF::FastMalloc> const&, WebKit::CallbackBase::Error>(WTF::Function<void + 1749196 (WTF::Vector<WebCore::Cookie, 0ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow, 16ul, WTF::FastMalloc> const&, WebKit::CallbackBase::Error)>&&) + 136
3   WebKit                          0x0000000193049008 WebKit::WebCookieManagerProxy::getAllCookies(PAL::SessionID, WTF::Function<void + 1749000 (WTF::Vector<WebCore::Cookie, 0ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow, 16ul, WTF::FastMalloc> const&, WebKit::CallbackBase::Error)>&&) + 44
4   WebKit                          0x0000000192eb5b90 API::HTTPCookieStore::cookies(WTF::Function<void + 97168 (WTF::Vector<WebCore::Cookie, 0ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow, 16ul, WTF::FastMalloc> const&)>&&) + 124
5   WebKit                          0x00000001931fbdf8 -[WKHTTPCookieStore getAllCookies:] + 92
6   WebKit                          0x00000001931fc96c WKHTTPCookieStoreObserver::cookiesDidChange+ 3533164 (API::HTTPCookieStore&) + 44
7   WebKit                          0x0000000192eb61b0 API::HTTPCookieStore::cookiesDidChange+ 98736 () + 72
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018a0e17d4 WTF::dispatchFunctionsFromMainThread+ 6100 () + 344
9   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018a208650 WTF::timerFired+ 1214032 (__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 40
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183527aa8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
11  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018352776c __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 864
12  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183527010 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 248
13  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183524b60 __CFRunLoopRun + 2168
14  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183444da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
15  WebCore                         0x000000018b6d1dcc RunWebThread+ 265676 (void*) + 592
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001831a5220 _pthread_body + 272
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001831a5110 _pthread_body + 0
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001831a3b10 thread_start + 4
```

Looks like there is an overflow when getAllCookies is called.This happens only in iOS 11.3.

Comment: Looks like you might need to file a bug report with Apple, see what they say: http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Were you able to resolve this crash? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Please see solution at the bottom https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954273/wkwebview-getallcookies-crash-in-ios-11-3/55397755#55397755 and accept if it works for you. The selected answer is not correct as threading is not a solution :) thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix this crash by calling getAllCookies asynchronously in the main thread.

```
func cookiesDidChange(in cookieStore: WKHTTPCookieStore) {
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
         cookieStore.getAllCookies { (cookies) in
             //Code here...
         })
     }
}
```

Comment: this is not solving the crash for me.

Comment: This doesn't solve the crash, the crash is not related to threading. Please see solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954273/wkwebview-getallcookies-crash-in-ios-11-3/55397755#55397755

Answer (score 8):

After some investigation we have come to the following **working** solution:

### Backstory

We have a crash when the user updates to a newer version of our App.

### Problem

We were using UIWebView and injecting cookies into it. The problem comes when:

- User installs new updated App which uses WKWebview.
- User opens a web view.
- We try to retrieve all the previously UIWebView injected cookies by calling `getAllCookies(_ completionHandler: @escaping ([HTTPCookie]) -> Void)` on the component `wkhttpcookiestore` so we can loop through them and remove them one by one.

### Verdict

UIWebView uses `nshttpcookiestorage`: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nshttpcookiestorage

WKWebView uses `wkhttpcookiestore`: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkhttpcookiestore

Somewhere in the middle of the synchronisation from `nshttpcookiestorage` to the `wkhttpcookiestore` when we try to retrieve the cookies, it is passing one of the values as a NSURL and then someone is calling `length()` function on that object which crashes because NSURL does not have that function.

### Resolution

Therefore, we should remove the cookies that are set on the `nshttpcookiestorage` with the right method which is by using:
`HTTPCookieStorage.shared.removeCookies(since: Date.distantPast)` and then remove the cookies from the `wkhttpcookiestore` with the right method that is `removeData(ofTypes:for:completionHandler:)` and set the type as `WKWebsiteDataTypeCookies` rather than looping through all the cookies and removing them one by one.

### Test Considerations

All tests MUST be done on real devices (iPhone/iPad) since this crash is NOT reproducible on iOS simulators.

### Code Snippet

```
public func clearCookies(completion: @escaping (() -> Swift.Void)) {
    // First remove any previous cookies set in the NSHTTP cookie storage.
    HTTPCookieStorage.shared.removeCookies(since: Date.distantPast)
    // Second remove any previous cookies set in the WKHTTP cookie storage.
    let typeCookiesToBeRemoved: Set<String> = [WKWebsiteDataTypeCookies]
    // Only fetch the records in the storage with a cookie type.
    WKWebsiteDataStore.default().fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: typeCookiesToBeRemoved) { records in
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        records.forEach { record in
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            WKWebsiteDataStore.default().removeData(ofTypes: record.dataTypes, for: [record], completionHandler: {
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            })
        }
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
            print("All cookies removed.")
            completion()
        }
    }
}
```