# How to set cookies in WKWebview using xamarin forms

Tags: c#, cookies, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I'm trying to switch my existing app from UIWebView to WKWebView. The app manages the users login / session outside of the webview. I'm using WKWebsiteDataStore for setting cookies, and its working in iOS 11+ , but in iOS 10 and below app is crashing.

Here is my Code

```
protected async void LoadCookies()
{
var cookieStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.DefaultDataStore;
var cookies = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.Cookies;
var oldcookies = await dataStore.HttpCookieStore.GetAllCookiesAsync();
foreach (var cookie in oldcookies)
{
    await cookieStore.HttpCookieStore.DeleteCookieAsync(cookie);
}
foreach (var cookie in cookies)
{
    await cookieStore.HttpCookieStore.SetCookieAsync(cookie);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please share us the stacktrace? Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954273/wkwebview-getallcookies-crash-in-ios-11-3/55397755#55397755) may help.

Comment: Exception:-Objective-c exception thrown Name:NSInvalidArgumentException Reason[WKWebsiteDataStore httpCookieStore] unrecognized selector sent

Answer (score 0):

If you read document about [httpCookieStore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebsitedatastore/2881956-httpcookiestore), you will find that `httpCookieStore` is available since iOS 11.0. That's why your app crash in iOS 10 and below.

You can have a with the solutions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573137/can-i-set-the-cookies-to-be-used-by-a-wkwebview) when in iOS 10 and below.

```
    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
    {
        foreach (var cookie in cookies)
        {
            await cookieStore.HttpCookieStore.SetCookieAsync(cookie);
        }
    }
    else
    {

        NSMutableUrlRequest request = new NSMutableUrlRequest(new Uri(""));
        request.ShouldHandleCookies = true;
        request.SetValueForKey(new NSString("123"), new NSString("Cookie"));
    }
```

Comment: The above code for iOS 11 and above is not working in 12 versions.